# Making Physics Predictions In Unity3D -

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm working on what is.. in short, an mmofpsrpg. I've been toying with a lot of ideas and recently I've been thinking:

I could in-fact delay the players acts a few frames, maybe three, and know three frames ahead of time where the player is going to be and make a trajectory based off these three vector points that they were on/going to be on.

I know the triple A FPS like COD and Battlefield are predicting movement in order to compensate for latency but I have no idea how they do it.

This leads me to wonder, how many ways can we structure logic in a format that allows us to make predictions about it?

Furthermore, what can we do with this data?

I know these are very open ended questions, but I do also feel like they are not opinion based and can have definitive answers.

So, in summation, my question is this:

> What are industry standards of predicting player movements in
>   three-dimensional spaced?

I'd also love to hear anyone else's ideas/solutions that are not industry standard per se, but it is not the main goal of this post.

**[Update: 10/11/2016]**

So, I've looked in to the matter and talk to a few industry heads. Along with @Jorge Santos' comment. General consensus, in-fact unanimous consensus says interpolation. Go figure. Well, the thing is this:

Interpolation is not so much a prediction but rather a last command, if you will. A stream of movement as opposed to the snapshots that actually provide the locations and physics data is helpful for making sure that impacts take place with latency and you don't get choppy movement, but what I was really after is predicting future movement. Whereas interpolation is saying hey, this is the direction I was going an have been going, and I have not been told to change this behaviour so I'm going to continue it.

So, the question now..

> In what ways can we *predict future movement*?

Comment: What you are looking for is "Interpolation", i sugest you search and study.
I dont know much about this topic, but see if this helps http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/ChristianArellano/20160329/269065/UNET_Unity_5_Networking_Entity_Interpolation_Part_1_of_6__Break_Into_Components.php

Comment: Sweet. Thanks brother.

Comment: Prediction algorithms are a entire field of study. This is way too broad for a stackoverflow.com question.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. It was kind of where I landed.

Comment: I upvoted your comment but then I clicked it again and undid it and now I can't do it again.